# Angular Route No Errors but Not Woking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

It's just simple but I don't know what's wrong. I have the following example, making a simple web template with angular ui-router and angular 1.2.16.

```
     <script type='text/javascript' src='angular.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='angular-ui-router.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/me/app.js'></script>
```

I've written the app.js and index.html something like this

app.js

```
angular.module('app',[
    'ui.router'

])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider'],function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    //console.log($urlRouterProvider);

    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/',
        templateUrl:'home.html'
    })
})
```

and the index.html is

```
    <body ng-app="app">
           <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
            <!-- End of Header -->
           <div ui-view="''"></div>
           <footer ng-include="'footer.html'"></footer></body>
```

My header and footer work properly. That is a good first step.  But when I try routes, nothing happens.

In my console there are no errors at all.. I don't understand, what is the matter?  I think it's quite simple.  Maybe because I'm very new to angular.  So, if you can suggest solutions out there, please help.

Comment: Can you try replacing <div ui-view="''"></div> with <div ui-view=""></div>. That is the default route that should be filled in with home.html.

Comment: still not working with <div ui-view=""></div> @rajasaur

Comment: Thanks for correct my english. Actualy, my english not quite well. @j.wittwer

Comment: Try this:   `<div ui-view></div>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

State change errors aren't shown in the console normally.  You will need to add an error listener like so in order to see what went wrong:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  $dialogs.error("Something went wrong!", error);
  console.error("$stateChangeError: ", toState, error);
});
```

Most likely your template isn't where you are specifying or something like that.

Comment: Where to put this code? I can't find any suitable place where `$rootscope` is available to inject...

Comment: Thankyou, this is a great tip!  Worth noting that the $dialogs reference is a little confusing for those that don't use it.

Comment: @Episodex: I put mine in the main module's run() function.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a bad path in my url:

> Check the URL! `http://example.com/#/` is not registered and $stateProvider won't tell you it's wrong.
>
> I simply had to **remove "`/#/`"** from my URL.

I suppose a hash got added on somewhere, but I had the same problem as OP: header and footer were fine, but nothing inside `<ui-view></ui-view>`

No idea why the devs would make it so that when you go to an unregistered path it gives no errors or indication of any kind that something bad happened, but there you go...

---

## How to permanently fix this issue:

`$stateProvider` overrides `$urlProvider`, so `.otherwise` won't work.

**Add an `otherwise` state:**

```
/// OP's code ///
$stateProvider
  .state('home',{
    url:'/',
    templateUrl:'home.html'
  })                       
  
                              // Just add a new state
  .state('otherwise',{
    url:'*path',              // uses regex, and doesn't mess up preceding state urls
    templateUrl: 'home.html'  // sends the user back home if a bad url happens
  })
```

---

## In response to using `$rootScope`

While [@GlenFilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521315/glenn-filson)'s answer did not provide any indication the path was incorrect, I was able to figure out *where* his answer should go:

```
var app = angular.module(...); // can't inject $rootScope here except through providers (e.g., $httpProvider)
app.config(...);               // nor here

// define app.run() after configuration

app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
      $dialogs.error("Something went wrong!", error);
      console.error("$stateChangeError: ", toState, error);
    });
})
```